# Probability all numbers will be selected?

Tags: probability

I have 500 tries to draw 1 from 250 balls, all labelled (1 to 250), from an urn (with replacement). Each of the 250 balls are equally likely to be selected.

What is the probability that I will, with the 500 tries, draw all 250 different balls at least once?

Comment: The win condition is fairly hard to calculate. Can you think about how to calculate the probably that you *won't* draw all the balls at least once? What's the likelihood that at least one ball doesn't get drawn at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is the coupon collector's problem with $n=250$ and $k=500$.

For the coupon collector's problem with $n$ objects, let $D$ be the number of draws needed to get a complete set. Then we have the formula $$\mathbb{P}(D\leq k)=n^{-k}\ n!\ \left\lbrace {k\atop n}\right\rbrace.$$ Here the braces indicate Stirling numbers of the second kind.
Plugging in $n=250$ and $k=500$ gives
$$\mathbb{P}(500 \mbox{ draws suffice})=250^{-500}\, 250!\,\left\lbrace{500 \atop 250}\right\rbrace =4.49220\times 10^{-18}\approx 0.$$ This means that the chance is practically zero.

The average number of draws to get a full collection with $n=250$ is 
$$250\left(1+{1\over 2}+{1\over 3}+\cdots+{1\over 250}\right)=1525.168,$$
so you need over 1500 draws to get a halfways decent chance to get all 250 balls at least once.

Comment: Wow, I actually rephrased this question as part of a database assignment, and learnt something new in probability theory. I initially tried to model it with the "birthday problem" but it seemed futile...right now, I have a new model to learn. Cheers man!

Comment: @bryansis2010 Glad to help. There is a lot of material on the coupon collector's problem available. You may start here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem