# What is the smallest unseen number in an iid sample? (From "A number NOBODY has thought of - Numberphile")

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, random-variables, recreational-mathematics

In [this Numberphile video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KdZrxkix9Mk), the question: "What is a number nobody has thought of?" is addressed. The method is as follows:

1. Estimate a number $N$ as the number of times humans have
   thought of numbers
2. Estimate a probability distribution
   $\mathbb{P}$ for what number you think of when you have a thought
   and suppose that each though is an independent draw from this
3. Calculate the distribution of the *maximum* of $N$ independent draws
   from $\mathbb{P}$

More precisely, this is the answering the question: "What is the **largest** number **someone** has thought of?" (and if you add 1 you will surely get a number nobody has thought of).

A more interesting question in my view is "What is the **smallest** number **nobody** has thought of?". If we agree with step 1 and step 2 from the Numberphile video, then this ammounts to:

What is the distribution of the smallest integer $I$ so that $N$ iid draws from a distribution $\mathbb{P}$ on the integers does not contain $I$. (In other words: the event that $\{I > x\}$ is the event that the numbers $\{1,\ldots,x\}$ *all* appear in our sample).

Surely someone has thought of this before....is there an elegant way to calculate this?

Comment: I would have thought this depends (a) on the distribution and (b) the number of people and (c) the particular case is that specific sample

Comment: Right: the problem is how do you comibine the number N and the distribution P to get the answer( for example, for the maximum seen number as they did the video, the answer is to do something like (1-P(X > x))^N). What is the right operation to do to get the minimum unseen number?

Comment: I just realized that the problem of finding the probability that all numbers from {1,...,x} are thought of in N thoughts is the coupon collector problem with unequal probabilities! So https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/600012/coupon-collectors-problem-with-unequal-probabilities  or https://mat.uab.cat/matmat_antiga/PDFv2014/v2014n02.pdf may be helpful